# Object can't convert to datetime? Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe and for some reason I can't convert it to datetime.  Anybody know what can be causing this?

```
Date
11/17/2017
11/16/2017  
11/15/2017
```

This code doesn't seem to be working

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

Error message

```
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "11/21/2013" at position 2
```

Comment: Try: df.Date=  `pd.to_datetime(df.Date, errors='coerce')`

Comment: ^hey coldspeed, thanks for the tip!  it did indeed work.  also cool username